# Установщик программы WPF из Visual Studio c правами администратора

Tags: visual-studio, установка, release-management, clickonce

После разработки программы необходимо создать установщик программы. В Visual Studio существует такая возможность с технологией ClickOnce, которая позволяет не только создать установщик, но и получать обновления "по воздуху".

Однако столкнулся с проблемой, которая не позволяет использовать эту технологию в связи с тем, что программа требует права администратора (requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" в манифест файле), которые необходимы для того, чтобы добавлять и убирать программу из автозапуска в системе с помощью изменения регистра системы.

- Есть ли возможность разрешить эту проблему или не стоит пользоваться этой технологией и лучше создать свой установщик программы? Соответственно необходимо будет создать свой способ обновления программы.
- Кроме этого, установщик Visual Studio не позволяет установить программу в необходимое пользователю место. Так задумано?
- Если создавать свой установщик, какие файлы необходимы для корректной работы программы? Как получить конечный результат программы со всеми иконками и библиотеками в одной папке?